# IBM Worklight - Dealing with version numbers

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-runtime

Is there a way I can make my Worklight's app public version number be different than the version number we're providing in application-descriptor.xml?

For example, I want my users to see the version `3.0.1` on Android settings (which is defined by the version attribute in the application-descriptor.xml) and one day I will want them to get an update from the Worklight server, but at that point I'd like that to turn into version `3.0.2`. The problem is that a `3.0.1` will not update against something on the Worklight server that is `3.0.2`.

Is there a way I can get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worklight does not provide this ability. IMO this is because what you're asking for is not inline with the thinking and intended usage of the Direct Update feature.

Direct Update is meant as a way to quickly provide fixes after having already released an app version to the store, for example in cases such as:

- discovery of minor or major UI or logic bugs you've found in the app, or
- for closing security holes that have been found

This is all happening **to the same app version** (lets say 3.0.1). Consider these as 3.0.1.**build** releases. or something.
It is not meant as a way of releasing new versions of the app. For this purpose use the conventional and appropriate way of releasing new app versions.

If you want to change the app version (which should coincide with a new app release), then you need to increase it in `application-descriptor.xml` (and other Worklight-related tasks), create a new binary and upload it to store, which users are then able to update and will see the new version number (lets say 3.0.2).